# Define IP address instead of localhost in when run web API in URL

Tags: asp.net-core, url, iis, localhost

I just started to writing code on asp.net core. I have been struggling in one trouble in WEB API. When I run my web API program on IIS server by defaults its use "http://localhost:5000" (5000)=>is port number.

But I would like to use my Machine IP address for example("http://192.168.1.110:5000/api/Controller") instead of localhost there. I tried using several other process but still does not work.

I also got some solution by publishing in IIS server and bind IP address. But I ignored it. I only need hard coding solution in my project file.

Comment: Did you fiind any solution?